# Checking if a sentence will fit a PDF box with javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

My PDF will only support two lines (I predefined the dimensions of the input box on the PDF).

Is there a way to check if user input on the front end will only make up to two lines on the PDF side? I tried to see if I could find character width lengths and then adding up the lengths of the characters the user enters, but that didn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The width of single character depends on particular font. But you may have fixed width characters with [fixed width fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) like `Courier` font so you may assume that all characters are the same width.  Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19114182/712093) to see how to measure width of the text element on HTML page.

PDF uses `72` DPI (Dots Per Inch) so if you have `A4` output PDF page size ( `8.25 x 11.75` inches) so the width in points is `72*8.25 = 594 points`. Assuming the text in PDF will use the same font and the same size so you may check if the width of the text fits `594` points to fit into PDF.